# Photologue vs. Imagestore?

Tags: python, django, image, gallery, photologue

So I was looking at:
http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/gallery/

because I need to add a gallery app to my project.

I noticed that Imagestore seems to be more actively maintained and have more features, but that more people by far are using Photologue.

I'm wondering why and welcome any advice on which I should use (and why!)

Comment: My experience with Photologue has been bad.  I haven't used it in a couple of years, but I recall there was a model in which the first line of the model's save() method called delete() on itself.  *facepalm*

Comment: @Casey Kinsey Yes, its `GalleryUpload` model. It is only used to upload a ZIP of images and to create `Photo` and `PhotoGallery` objects out of them. It's not really sinful as you make it sound. Biggest problem with photologue is that it has not been maintained for some time. Also any reference to alternative applications is welcomed.

Comment: @rebus, I would say it shows a pretty big lack of understanding in Django (and Python's) core methodology.  I think the OP has the answer already though, after checking the grid I'd go with Imagestore for the same reasons she suggested.  I'm not offering that as an answer though, as I've never used it in a project either so I lack first hand experience.